# Peta Poco: How to pass multiple parameters to a Fetch<T>

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, petapoco

My Code:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM people where birthday >= @t1 AND birthday <= @t2"
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000");
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2001");
var results = db.Fetch<Person>(sql, t1,t2);
```

This code produces an error:

```
additional information: Parameter '@t1' specified but none of the passed arguments  have a property with this name (in 'SELECT......
```

I wish to know what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with petapoco, but by the error message, it seems to be trying to bind the parameters to the *property* of the object you pass in to the `Fetch` call.  If so, try something like this instead:

```
var results = db.Fetch<Person>(sql, new {t1 = t1, t2 = t2});
```

Comment: Shorter version: `var results = db.Fetch<Person>(sql, new {t1, t2});`

Comment: @Eduardo: Hey, thanks.  Didn't know that you could infer the property names that way.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) isn't overly direct, but for positional parameters you need to use zero-indexed placeholder names `@0`, `@1`... in your query. Try:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM people where birthday >= @0 AND birthday <= @1"
```

If you use named placeholders, PetaPoco looks for an object with that property name, hence the error message you're getting. For example:

```
sql.Append("AND date_created>=@start AND date_created<=@end", 
    new 
        { 
            start=DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2), 
            end=DateTime.UtcNow 
        }
    );
```